# Cronjob script fails but manually runs fine

Tags: aix

I have script which runs manually fine but not getting the desired output when run through cronjob. Please let me know if anything wrong with the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

file1=$(find *-* -mtime 1)

file2=$(find *-* -mtime 2)


basefile1=$(basename $file1)
basefile2=$(basename $file2)


cd /gtxappl/Release/SCMAudit

./cmp.sh $basefile1 $basefile2 > dailyAuditChecks.txt

mailx -s "Daily Checks Report" ****@homeretailgroup.com < dailyAuditChecks.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

From [Admin's Choice](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference):

```
5. Crontab Environment
cron invokes the command from the user’s HOME directory with the shell, (/usr/bin/sh).
cron supplies a default environment for every shell, defining:
HOME=user’s-home-directory
LOGNAME=user’s-login-id
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:.
SHELL=/usr/bin/sh
Users who desire to have their .profile executed must explicitly do so in the crontab entry or in a script called by the entry.
```

I recommend using absolute paths wherever possible and don't forget about executing your .profile if you need environment variables.

Comment: When in doubt, add a printenv command to the script to find what the environment actually looks like.